# Shortest Distance between two points on a 2D surface

Tags: differential-equations, differential-geometry, variational-calculus

I am working on an interesting problem, that consists of trying to compute the shortest distance between two points on a 2D surface. This 2D surface can be represented in a 3D space by the function $f(x,y)=z$. To do this, I solve the geodesic equation and compute the arc length of the solution $\{x_\text{sol}(t),y_\text{sol}(t)\}$ where $t$ will be the parameter to describe the trajectory. However when I test my solution for simple cases I get slightly wrong results and I am not sure why. Here is an example:

### Generate surface and points:

```
f[x_, y_] := -x^2 - y^2 + 1
{x0, y0} = {0, 0};
{x1, y1} = {0, Sin[Pi/2]};
surface = 
  ContourPlot3D[f[x, y] == z, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[0.8]}];
ptsPlot = 
  ListPointPlot3D[{{x0, y0, f[x0, y0]}, {x1, y1, f[x1, y1]}}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.05]}];
Show[surface, ptsPlot]
Show[ContourPlot[f[0, y] == z, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 2}, 
  ContourStyle -> Black], 
 ListPlot[{{y0, f[0, y0]}, {y1, f[0, y1]}}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.05]}]]
```

[image]

I chose points that are aligned on the $x$-axis so that I can easily test my answer: in this case, the shortest distance will be a trajectory on the $yz$-plane. The distance will the length of the following curve:

[image]

### Find Geodesic

Then, to solve the geodesic equation I compute the Lagragian, and use a package `VariationalMethods` that solves the Euler Lagrange equation for me:

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

(*Find Lagrangian by computing the metric from the line element*)
Lagrange = (1 + D[f[x[t], y[t]], x[t]]^2)*
    x'[t]^2 + (1 + D[f[x[t], y[t]], y[t]]^2)*y'[t]^2 + 
   2*D[f[x[t], y[t]], x[t]]*D[f[x[t], y[t]], y[t]];

(*Mathematica differentiates everything and writes down the Euler \
Lagrange Equation for us*)
{eq1, eq2} = 
  EulerEquations[Lagrange, {x[t], y[t]}, {t}];

(*Solve it, nb: since we only care about the distance we can put any \
time interval*)

S = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, x[0] == x0, x[1] == x1, y[0] == y0, 
    y[1] == y1}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1}];
xsol[t_] := Evaluate[x[t] /. S[[1, 1]]]
ysol[t_] := Evaluate[y[t] /. S[[1, 2]]]
solution = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{xsol[t], ysol[t], f[xsol[t], ysol[t]]}, {t, 0, 1},
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[surface, solution, ptsPlot]
```

### Verify solution

However if I plot the solution I obtain we can see that it is slightly off:

[image]

In fact, if I compute the error by calculating the arclength of the true trajectory, I have almost an error of almost $20\%$ :

```
distance = NIntegrate[ Sqrt[xsol'[t]^2 + ysol'[t]^2], {t, 0, 1}] (*Arc Length*)
(*1.19323*)
trueDistance = ArcLength[1 - y^2, {y, 0, 1}] // N
(*1.47894*)
```

Which is not desirable at all. How could I improve this method? What am I doing wrong?

### Edit:

Daniel Huber's comment made the trick: now it works really well! here is the plot of solution for the example I used:

[image]

### Second Edit:

I found examples where this notebook fails to give me the shortest distance, for example use:

```
(* Define Surface*)
f[x_, y_] := 1/(x^2 + y^2 + 0.2)
surface = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];

(*Determine points*)
{x0, y0} = {-1, -1};
{x1, y1} = {1, 1};
ptsPlot = 
  ListPointPlot3D[{{x0, y0, f[x0, y0]}, {x1, y1, f[x1, y1]}}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.05]}];
Show[surface, ptsPlot]
```

[image]

This tells me that the trajectory is by climbing the summit of the mountain, which must be clearly wrong. Is this an error in the NDSolve?

Comment: I think your line element is wrong. It should be Sqrt[D[r,t].D[r,t]] where r is the position vectors of the surface: r= {x[t],y[t],f[x[t],y[t]]}

Comment: It works incredibly well now, thank you! Do you have a link or reference that explains why the line element is Sqrt[D[r,t].D[r,t]] ? What happens in the case where I have a closed surface?

Comment: It is no magic, only simple math: if r[t] is a position vector dependent on t, then an infinite increment is : ds= D[r[t],t] . dt. And the length of the infinite increment, the line element, is: Sqrt[ds.ds]= Sqrt[r'.r'] dt. This will also work on closed surfaces.

Comment: I found an example where this does not work, is it due to the function NDSolve or other numerical errors? It would be great if this routine would be robust against all kinds of simple surfaces –

Comment: The Euler Lagrange equation gives you stationary path. That is small changes do not change the pathlength in linear approximation. Therefore, you can get a maximal path as well as a minimal one. Try perturbing the initial stat a bit.

Comment: Try calculating the pathlength with a middle point that is not exactly on the original path and check if the pathlength decreases.

Comment: If I change the position of the peak so that the maximum trajectory is not a straight line anymore, my computer cannot solve the equation anymore. I think I will have to settle with the current situation, thanks for the help: this was very useful!